# PHP truncating string when using strip_tags

Tags: php, escaping, pyrocms, strip-tags

I have this stored in my MySQL InnoDB UTF8 database:

> `<p>`At 5'1" (155cm) in length, this "Baby" grand piano was introduced
>   in the 1930's and features the powerful and rich tone of a much larger
>   piano. Small enough to fit nicely into almost any room, this piano is
>   handcrafted using the same materials and techniques that go into
>   making our concert grand pianos.`</p>`

When I echo strip_tags($string), PHP returns this:

`Introduced 5\'1\`

And that's it. I found a similar reported bug [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45599) (affected having slashes, not single/double quotes) but it was resolved. I'm using PHP 5.3.6.

Any idea how I can resolve this without needing to use `preg_replace`?

Comment: `strip_tags()` is not really safe. See this (mayby sligtly biased) [comparison](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#Summary)

Comment: Please post the PHP code which retrieves, strips, and displays this.  The bug doesn't seem like the source of this..

Comment: can't reproduce with 5.4.5-dev. You could try `stripslashes(strip_tags(addslashes($str)))` as a workaround. no idea if that helps since i can't reproduce it.

Comment: I'm using PyroCMS / PyroStreams, both of which use the Lex parser. So I built a plugin that just does a simple strip_tag. My Lex markup looks like this: {{ useful:striptags value=short_description }} and my Useful class looks like this: function striptags() { return strip_tags($this->attribute('value')); }

Comment: Alright, so I changed the line return strip_tags($this->attribute('value')); to just return $this->attribute('value'), and I get the same error. So this tells me it's not a strip tag error but an error with PyroCMS or Lex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the Lex parser that PyroCMS uses. The fix can be found here:

https://github.com/happyninjas/lex/commit/ff9aa30554fce47a8bfb6dc7c94143afc2fd8f93

I also committed the change to PyroCMS. Hopefully it gets implemented for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Is this inside a input? because the quote will end it.

try htmlentities(strip_tags($string));

```
<input type="text" value="Introduced 5\'1\" (155......" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```php
<?php

$pattern = '/<.*?>/';
$string  = '<p>At 5\'1" (155cm) in length, this "Baby" grand piano was introduced in the 1930\'s and features the powerful and rich tone of a much larger piano. Small enough to fit nicely into almost any room, this piano is handcrafted using the same materials and techniques that go into making our concert grand pianos.</p>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);

?>
```

Comment: `$pattern = '/<[^>]+>/';` should be faster for large strings. though "parsing" html with regex is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree that trying to parse HTML with RegEx is not a good idea. However RegEx can be used to do simple tasks like stipping tags.